# Idea Intellij doesn't see classes's metamodels

Tags: intellij-idea, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I use JPA 2.0 and criteria queries. For criteria queries I need metamodels of classes, so I've added `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor` in Idea Intellij and set 'generated' folder for metamodels. Also I've added dependence `'hibernate-jpamodelgen'` in build.gradle file. After building project I can see `'generated'` folder with metamodels. When I start to use metamodels Idea doesn't see their(can't import), so I need write name of metamodels manually. After that there is error, `'Can't resolve symbols...'`, but I can compile without compile errors. Can I fix that Idea imports metamodels? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-150042 and the linked issues. There is a workaround suggested in the comments how to adjust Gradle source roots configuration so that IntelliJ IDEA recognizes the generated sources folder.

Comment: CrazyCoder: thank you